# One result array

Tags: php

I'm trying to add the results of a script to an array, but once I look into it there is only one item in it, probably me being silly with placement

```
function crawl_page($url, $depth)
{
    static $seen = array();
    $Linklist = array();

    if (isset($seen[$url]) || $depth === 0) {
        return;
    }
    $seen[$url] = true;

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    @$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);

    $anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach ($anchors as $element) {
        $href = $element->getAttribute('href');
        if (0 !== strpos($href, 'http')) {
            $href = rtrim($url, '/') . '/' . ltrim($href, '/');
        }
        if(shouldScrape($href)==true)
        {
          crawl_page($href, $depth - 1);
        }

    }
    echo "URL:",$url;
    echo http_response($url);
    echo  "<br/>";
    $Linklist[] = $url;

    $XML = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $XML->formatOutput = true;

    $root = $XML->createElement('Links');
    $root = $XML->appendChild($root);

    foreach ($Linklist as $value)
    {    
        $child = $XML->createElement('Linkdetails');
        $child = $root->appendChild($child);

        $text = $XML->createTextNode($value);
        $text = $child->appendChild($text);
    }        
    $XML->save("linkList.xml");      
}
```

Comment: Where are you adding something to an array? Please explain in more detail what goes wrong. Where does the expected result differ from the actual result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$Linklist[] = $url;` will add a single item to the `$Linklist` array. This line needs to be in a loop I think.

Answer (score 0):

`static $Linklist = array();` i think, but code is awful